# JSON Schema conditional validation on multiple items only works when 1 item is present

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "term": {
        "units": "liters",
        "termType": "material"
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "units": "kilogram",
        "termType": "crop"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to validate that:

- if any element in `inputs` has `termType=material`
- then the `units` should be `kilogram`

So I wrote validation like this:

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "required": [
          "inputs"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "inputs": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "term": {
                  "properties": {
                    "termType": {
                      "const": "material"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "inputs": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "term": {
                  "properties": {
                    "units": {
                      "const": "kilogram"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using ajv version 6 to validate (with draft 07 enabled), and it works only when the `inputs` array has a single element in it, so if I run it on

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "term": {
        "units": "liters",
        "termType": "material"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

it will give an error, but not using the sample on top with 2 items in the array. Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

In general, constraints like this are defined this way in JSON Schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "properties": {
    "inputs": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/inputsItem" }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "inputsItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "term": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "termType": { "type": "string" },
            "units": { "type": "string" }
          },
          "required": [ "units" ]
        }
      },
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "term": {
            "properties": {
              "termType": { "const": "material" }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "term": {
            "properties": {
              "units": { "const": "kilogram" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```